# Using shared preferences to save events to flutter table calendar

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to allow users to add events to a calendar and then save those events with shared preferences.  When I run my code, there are a couple problems.  The first time I try to enter an event into the calendar, it doesn't show up, but the other events do show up.  However, when I hot restart or go to another page of my app and then come back to the calendar, the events don't save, and I get the error "Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, List>".  I think that part of the problem is in either my decodeMap function or my call of the decodeMap function, but any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```dart
class CalendarRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CalendarRouteState createState() => _CalendarRouteState();
}

class _CalendarRouteState extends State<CalendarRoute> {
  CalendarFormat format = CalendarFormat.month;
  DateTime selectedDay = date;
  DateTime focusedDay = date;
  late Map<DateTime, List<Event>> events;
  late List<dynamic> selectedEvents;
  TextEditingController _eventController = TextEditingController();
  late SharedPreferences prefs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    events = {};
    selectedEvents = [];
    prefsData();
  }

  Future prefsData() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      events = Map<DateTime, List<Event>>.from(
          decodeMap(jsonDecode(prefs.getString("events") ?? "{}")));
    });
  }

  Map<String, List<Event>> encodeMap(Map<DateTime, dynamic> map) {
    Map<String, List<Event>> newMap = {};
    map.forEach((key, value) {
      newMap[key.toString()] = map[key];
      print("EncodeMap");
      print(map[key]);
      print(map[value]);
      print(newMap[key.toString()]);
    });
    return newMap;
  }

  Map<DateTime, dynamic> decodeMap(Map<String, List<Event>> map) {
    Map<DateTime, dynamic> newMap = {};
    map.forEach((key, value) {
      print(map[key]);
      newMap[DateTime.parse(key)] = map[key];
    });
    return newMap;
  }

  List<Event> _getEventsFromDay(DateTime date) {
    return events[date] ?? [];
  }

  void dispose() {
    _eventController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Calendar", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
      ),
      body: Column(children: [
        TableCalendar(
            firstDay: DateTime.utc(2021, 6, 8),
            lastDay: DateTime.utc(2022, 6, 8),
            focusedDay: focusedDay,
            calendarFormat: format,
            onFormatChanged: (CalendarFormat _format) {
              setState(() {
                format = _format;
              });
            },
            startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
            onDaySelected: (DateTime selectDay, DateTime focusDay) {
              setState(() {
                selectedDay = selectDay;
                focusedDay = focusDay;
              });
            },
            selectedDayPredicate: (DateTime day) {
              return isSameDay(selectedDay, day);
            },
            eventLoader: _getEventsFromDay,
            calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                isTodayHighlighted: true,
                selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                ),
                selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                todayDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.brown,
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                )),
            headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                formatButtonVisible: true,
                titleCentered: true,
                formatButtonShowsNext: false,
                formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.brown,
                ),
                formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow))),
        ..._getEventsFromDay(selectedDay)
            .map((Event event) => ListTile(title: Text(event.title))),
      ]),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () => showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("Add event"),
                    content: TextFormField(
                      controller: _eventController,
                    ),
                    actions: [
                      TextButton(
                        child: Text("Cancel"),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                          child: Text("Ok"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (_eventController.text.isEmpty) {
                            } else if (events[selectedDay] != null) {
                              events[selectedDay]!.add(
                                Event(title: _eventController.text),
                              );
                            } else {
                              events[selectedDay] = [
                                Event(title: _eventController.text)
                              ];
                            }
                            //SettingsPreferences.saveEvents(events);
                            prefs.setString("events",
                                jsonEncode(encodeMap(events).toString()));
                            print(jsonEncode(encodeMap(events).toString()));
                            print(
                                jsonDecode(prefs.getString("events") ?? "{}"));
                            print(prefs.getString("events") ?? "{}");
                            _eventController.clear();
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                            setState(() {});
                            return;
                          }),
                    ])),
        label: Text("Add event"),
        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: new Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm_rounded),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/splashRoute');
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.fastfood),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/lunch');
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.map_outlined),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/resources');
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/settings');
              },
            ),
          ])),
    );
  }
}
```

Event class:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Event{
  final String title;
  Event({required this.title});
  String toString() => this.title;
}
```

Comment: a quick tip to start debugging efficiently: look for the line number in the error

Comment: do you have your `Event` class?

Comment: Oh yeah, here is my event class:                                                                       import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Event{
  final String title;
  Event({required this.title});
  String toString() => this.title;
}